# (Nuxtjs+ Firebase Firestore) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, firebase-security

i use Nuxt.js + Firebase Firestore and i try to get data from collection name is TestCollection but show

> Error getting document: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

[image: here is my firestore collection.]

my localhost display this.

```
Error getting document: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new n (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:188)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:10426)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:10427)
    at n.onMessage (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:10449)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:10366)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:10397)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:15160)
    at eval (prebuilt-306f43d8-45d6f0b9.js?a6a6:15218)
```

here is method who call collection.

```
async testPost(){
      try{
         await this.$fire.firestore.collection('TestCollection').get()
          .then((docs) => {
            console.log('docs:', docs)
          if (docs) {
            docs.forEach((doc) => {
              console.log(doc.data())
            })
          } else {
            console.log('No such document!')
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting document:', error)
        })
      }catch (err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    },
```

in nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    ['@nuxtjs/firebase', {
      config: {
        apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
        storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
        messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
        appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
        measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
      },

      services: {
        firestore: true,
        storage: true,
        database: true,
      },
    }],
  ],
```

in database.rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "false"
      }
    },
    "cases": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

in filetore.rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rules allow nobody to read any data from Firestore:

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
```

So the fact that your code that tries to read data from the database gets rejected by these rules is working as intended.

These are the default rules, so I highly recommend reading the documentation on securing your database both for [Firestore specifically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and for [Firebase overall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).

---

You'll want to start with the minimal change to your rules that allows your code to work, known as the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). Given the code you shared, that'd be:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /TestCollection/{doc} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

So now we allow anyone in the world to read the entire `TestCollection`, as that's what your code seems to do, but we still disallow all other operations.

Comment: now, i use  allow read: if true for some document.Thank a lot ^ ^