# Should I query my Firebase database directly, or use Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Currently I have a user collection with user documents inside and each user has a **currentPoints** integer field that can get updated from inside the application via a button click

```
                                    transaction
                                    .update(couponCollectionReference, {
                                  'currentPoints':
                                      FieldValue.increment(10),
                                });
```

If someone decided to reverse engineer my app, can they just change the increment to **FieldValue.increment(1000)** instead, compile the app and just use it like that ?

I am wondering if I should just use cloud functions for the major of these operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are designed to protect against race conditions between multiple users, but are not a security mechanism against abuse.

You can catch many forms of abuse in the server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) that you can write for your database. I've written secure voting systems with that, so likely your case can be secured through rules too.

If you [search for the `[google-cloud-firestore][firebase-security]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore+firebase-security) tag combination, you'll find many questions about the topic.

That said, many developers new to Firebase's security rules are more familiar with securing access through server-side code, which is fine too.

Comment: Thank you for responding Frank, so if I got this correctly, I can edit my security rules so that the only value that can be added to **currentPoints** is 10, and if anything else is tring to be written to it it will simply deny ?

Also I was wondering if I have a boolean field **isVisible** inside a different collection that can only be read by users, and that field decides if a widget inside the app is visible or not, can a user just change that value to **true** instead of **isVisible** so the widget is always visible on his screen ?

Comment: Security rules don't control what is showing on your screen. But if your application code reads whether it needs to show that button from a fixed location in the  database (so without a query), then your security rules can indeed enforce that the corresponding write operation can also only be performed under that condition. I recommend trying such operations, and posting back with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for taking out your time to shed some light on this worry of mine. I guess I still don't know enough about security that I worry about someone changing my code and being able to change anything they want in the firebase database

Comment: That is quite normal, but it's something we can't take away for you. I recommend reading the documentation ([1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics)) watching these videos ([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBUk293QSKY), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PEdd2rtG30), [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyZQBC-KSuM)), and trying to build your own rules and then to break them.

Comment: The most important is usually to start from the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege): start with a fully locked down database, and then only allow exactly what your code does. For more on that see my answers to these questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69404979/what-security-rules-should-be-applied-to-reads-in-firebase/69407457#69407457), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471480/nuxtjs-firebase-firestore-firebaseerror-missing-or-insufficient-permissions/70474221#70474221))